Question About Ideal Gas and Average Free Movement of Molecules
I have a question regarding the ideal gas and the average free movement of a single molecule. For simplicity, let's consider a model where we have only one atom moving, and we assume all atoms have the same radius.
First, we calculate the cross-section σ using the formula $\sigma=d^2$, where $d$ is the diameter of the atom. After obtaining the cross-section, we calculate the average free movement $\lambda$.
Next, we multiply these two values, $\sigma \cdot \lambda$ to find the volume associated with the average movement.
However, I wonder if this formula is correct. Shouldn't we also consider adding a half-sphere at the end of the cylinder to account for potential collisions? Would the complete expression then be $\sigma \cdot \lambda + (4 \pi d)/2$?
Thank you for your insights!

A system of hard spheres of diameter $d$ is not an ideal gas unless the density is so small that the difference between diameter and radius becomes irrelevant.

Yes thats correct, it was not 100% precise.  But under these conditions you could calculate as I suggested, right? How would you calculate the average freedom of movement if the diameter is 0?

In a perfect gas, there is no interaction between particles. There are only interactions between particles and walls. People can calculate the mean free path in a dilute gas. But strictly speaking, that is not a perfect gas.

As far as I know the term, an ideal gas is characterized by the fact that there are only elastic collisions between the particles (and the particles and the walls), but no attractive forces between the particles. I'll take another look at Atkins.

As soon as there is an interaction between particles, some deviation from the equation of state $pV=nRT$ appears.

Yes, I know the equation. But what I'm interested in is that I want to calculate a line under the conditions mentioned above, with the corresponding volume, and I want to determine exactly how far the ideal particles move on average, with a corresponding change in volume. I'm dealing with a theoretical model here, but I want to calculate it exactly. Hence my question about the hemisphere, which I can add to the cylinder or not. Here an image of my problem: https://www.physicsforums.com/attachments/stosszylinder-png.352712/

@GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 when you say no interaction between ideal gas molecules, don’t you mean no intermolecular attraction or repulsion forces? Can’t there be ideal elastic collisions between the molecules?

@BobD I mean, there is no interaction at all between molecules. That's equivalent to having zero-diameter spherical molecules. The model with a finite diameter is the well-known hard-sphere model, whose equation of state is not of ideal gas form.

The figure you linked about the cross-section of hard spheres is explicit: $\sigma = \pi d^2$.

@GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90. To quote from the Hyperphysics website “An ideal gas is defined as one in which all collisions between atoms or molecules are perfectly elastic and in which there are no intermolecular attractive forces. One can visualize it as a collection of perfectly hard spheres which collide but which otherwise do not interact with each other”. See:
http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Kinetic/idegas.html

@BobD I do not rely on web pages. Statistical Mechanics says the only way to get the ideal gas equation of state is when the Hamiltonian contains only the kinetic energy term. If one likes, it would be possible to say that the ideal gas is the limit of a hard-sphere system when the diameter vanishes.  But the final consequence is untouched. Point-like particles have zero probability of a mutual elastic collision.

@GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 Neither do I, but it’s a reputable website. I’m not conversant in statistical mechanics, but I ask you this: if two containers of ideal gases at a different temperatures are mixed how do you propose that the mixture will arrive at some final equilibrium temperature without higher KE molecules transferring KE to lower KE molecules via collisions?

@GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 Here’s another reputable website. Note item 4 https://chem.libretexts.org/Courses/University_of_California_Davis/UCD_Chem_002A/UCD_Chem_2A/Text/Unit_III%3A_Physical_Properties_of_Gases/06.07_Kinetic_Molecular_Theory_of_Gases

@BobD That's a well-known delicate point in the kinetic theory of gases. On the one hand, the perfect gas has no interparticle interaction; on the other hand, some interaction is required to allow the chaotic dynamics required for equilibration, ergodic theory, and so on. The key point is in a limit that should be managed carefully. The elastic collisions the last site mentions are there only to ensure thermal equilibrium (achieving a Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution). If we take the presence of interactions between point particles seriously, we should conclude with a zero cross-section.
